# cant see any map type other then normal (googlemap)

Tags: android, google-maps

i have create simple google map program from google map tutorial in developer site . then i change the mode of map to satellite or hybrid from normal it show me nothing .

i can only see the map in normal view . and other then that everything comes in gray grid.

please do suggest what might be solution . please mention if any extra information is needed.

thank you

**mainactivity**

```
package com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
MapFragment mapFragment;
GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.hide();
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });

    mapFragment= (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.hybrid) {
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        return true;
    }
    else if(id==R.id.normal){
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        return true;
    }
    else if(id==R.id.none){
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
        return true;
    }
    else if(id==R.id.satellite){
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        return true;
    }
    else if(id==R.id.terrain){
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map=googleMap;
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(20, 85)).title("Marker"));
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
}
}
```

[Hybrid Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrgEd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/4jQeXO8ctH8) about the problem you are facing.

These are some of the solutions recommended:

> Step 1) Are you using Firefox 3 and do you have Skype installed? If 
>   so, remove the Skype extension. This is known to break Google Maps and 
>   other websites.
>
> Step 2) Check these help topics:
>
> - http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=21849&topic=10789
> - http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=18529&topic=10789
>
> Step 3) Try loading a tile URL directly, by opening the following 
>   links:
>
> - http://mt2.google.com/mt/v=w2.0&hl=en&x=2&y=6&z=4&s=Gali 
>     You should see a roadmap for part of America.
> - http://khm0.google.com/kh?v=99&hl=en&x=0&y=0&z=1&s= 
>     You should see an image of the Earth from space.